# Custom mosaic view in Android?

Tags: android, mosaic

I am Working in an application where I have to design a Mosaic view. I have seen **Quilt Library** for the similar task but that doesn't provide a CUSTOM view that I am looking for in my application.

Please suggest me.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You want to implement a StaggeredGridView. Try [this](https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid) library.

Answer (score 1):

As what I see, [QuiltViewLibrary](https://github.com/jacobmoncur/QuiltViewLibrary) supports imageview and other view both. What you need to do is that create your own custom views the add them to QuiltViewLibrary

```
    ArrayList<View> views = new ArrayList<View>();
    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
        FrameLayout patch = new FrameLayout(this.getApplicationContext());
        views.add(patch);
    }
    quiltView.addPatchViews(views);
```

Comment: I had an issue loading images with Glide, which seemed not to respect center crop scaling when the `ImageView`s were directly added to the quilt through `addPatchImages`. Using a layout (I chose `RelativeLayout` for no reason, but I believe it works with any layout) to wrap the `ImageView`s and adding the layout through `addPatchViews` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at the Android SDK's [`RecyclerView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) with their [`StaggeredGridLayoutManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html). Examples of use can be found [here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview#layouts) and [here](https://inducesmile.com/android/android-staggeredgridlayoutmanager-example-tutorial/).